# Create 2 records from JSON Array having Structs

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON array which is in format below:

```
{
"id": "1",
"active": "True",
"gender": "female",
"coding": [
            {
              "system": "http://loinc.org",
              "code": "8310-5",
              "display": "Body temperature"
            },
            {
              "system": "http://loinc.org",
              "code": "8716-3",
              "display": "Vital Signs grouping"
            }
          ]
}
```

- I need output as two records. is it possible can someone help me with the Python code

```
{"id": "1","active": "True","gender": "female",{"system": "http://loinc.org","code": "8310-5","display": "Body temperature"},
{"id": "1","active": "True","gender": "female",{"system": "http://loinc.org","code": "8716-3","display": "Vital Signs grouping"}
```

Comment: `{"id": "1","active": "True","gender": "female",{"system":` This is broken json and python, every object value must have a key. Please check this and edit your post. Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import json
input_dict = json.loads(myjson)

base = input_dict.copy()
base.pop('coding')
output = [dict(base, **c) for c in input_dict['coding']]

print(output)
```

Output:

```
[{'active': 'True', 'code': '8310-5', 'display': 'Body temperature', 'gender': 'female', 'id': '1', 'system': 'http://loinc.org'},
{'active': 'True', 'code': '8716-3', 'display': 'Vital Signs grouping', 'gender': 'female', 'id': '1', 'system': 'http://loinc.org'}]
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish, One help i need each record in a separate line without the outer square brackets , is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you want the codings in their own key since your question wasn't clear

```
import json
obj = json.loads(s)  # where s is your json string

objs = []  # where we will store the results
for coding in obj['coding']:
    new_obj = obj.copy()
    new_obj['coding'] = coding  # set the coding entry to one coding
    objs.append(new_obj)
```

Output of `objs`:

```
[{'active': 'True',
  'coding': {'code': '8310-5',
             'display': 'Body temperature',
              'system': 'http://loinc.org'},
  'gender': 'female',
  'id': '1'},
 {'active': 'True',
  'coding': {'code': '8716-3',
             'display': 'Vital Signs grouping',
             'system': 'http://loinc.org'},
  'gender': 'female',
  'id': '1'}]
```

---

If you want just a flat dict then

```
objs = []
for coding in obj['coding']:
    new_obj = obj.copy()
    del new_obj['coding']
    new_obj.update(coding)
    objs.append(new_obj)
```

Now `objs` is:

```
[{'active': 'True',
  'code': '8310-5',
  'display': 'Body temperature',
  'gender': 'female',
  'id': '1',
  'system': 'http://loinc.org'},
 {'active': 'True',
  'code': '8716-3',
  'display': 'Vital Signs grouping',
  'gender': 'female',
  'id': '1',
  'system': 'http://loinc.org'}]
```

Comment: My requirement is whenever there is a struct in JSON file it should be convert to multiple records according to values in struct. here is the actual JSON file on S3 bucket, Please have a look at it.:  https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/anand-s3-input/New+Text+Document.json

Comment: @Anand well I'm not surprised. This json is a completely different structure to the one you described. The idea behind my answer should be trivial to convert for that json. SO is **not** a free coding service.

Comment: Hi Mitchell, I understand that that's why i did'nt sent the whole json , i will figure a way to unnest those arrays.One help if you can do is how do i make each record in a separate line without the outer square brackets. Would greatly appreciate your help. this is the format i want my output to be. [{'active': 'True','coding': {'code': '8310-5','display': 'Body temperature','system': 'http://loinc.org'},'gender': 'female','id': '1'},
{'active': 'True','coding': {'code': '8716-3','display': 'Vital Signs grouping','system': 'http://loinc.org'},'gender': 'female','id': '1'}]